# Augmented reality in iOS 5 VS. iOS 4 - Textures not load after deployment

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, textures, augmented-reality

I am using qualcomm's ar sdk, I have added the Eaglview to one of my view controllers.
The project builds successfully and run perfectly on iOS 4. On the other hand, the project deploys successfully and also runs like a charm on iOS 5 on for the first time it's debugged.

The problem is that once the application is already installed on the device (iphone 4 and 4S iOS 5) the textures are never loaded again. I am obliged to delete the application from the device and debug again to see textures.

PS: the ImageTargets sample runs perfectly every time on both iOS. Unlike my project where I have an ARViewController, the Eaglview in the Qualcomm sample (ImageTargets) is called from the AppDelegate.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

so this problem doesn't occur on Qualcomm sample?

Do you receive an error message concerning the texture failure?

You should check if you´re sending correctly all the textures you need as resources and including them in your XCode project. Make sure you're calling the correct resource when you load the texture.

Comment: No error concerning texture loading failure, the code works fine in the ImageTarget project. I tried copying all my code (application's viewcontrollers and libraries) to the sample project, the problem persists (3D object loading without textures).

Comment: I found the problem in my code using the Opengl Es analyser instrument in Xcode 4. I got the error saying "Uninitialized Texture Data" in my RenderFrame() method. The data seems to be initialized only on the first run. How to solve this? Should be initializing the Texture Data in the renderFrame()? It does not seem like the best solution.